# How to create a tablespace with multiple datafiles?

Tags: oracle

I'm using the following script to create a new tablespace with three datafile with 4 MB size for each.

```
create tablespace homeworkts 
       datafile 'D:\oradata\orcl\df1.dbf' size 4m , 
       datafile 'D:\oradata\orcl\df2.dbf' size 4m,
       datafile 'D:\oradata\orcl\df3.dbf' size 4m;
```

But it keeps giving me the error

> invalid file name

for the second datafile.

Why?

Answer (score 11):

Reading [create tablespace syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7003.htm) you should write:

```
create tablespace homeworkts 
datafile 'D:\oradata\orcl\df1.dbf' size 4m, 
         'D:\oradata\orcl\df2.dbf' size 4m, 
         'D:\oradata\orcl\df3.dbf' size 4m;
```

You should write `datafile` just for once, then all your file specification separated by commas:

[image]

**Edited on 2018'** Still valid for current [create tablespace on release 18 oracle version](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLESPACE.html).

Answer (score 2):

It should be like this

```
 create tablespace homeworkts datafile 'D:\oradata\orcl\df1.dbf' size 4m, 

'D:\oradata\orcl\df2.dbf' size 4m,

'D:\oradata\orcl\df3.dbf' size 4m;
```

Comment: Looks lik eyou @danihp by two seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
create tablespace userdata 
       datafile 'E:\oradata\orcl\df1.dbf' size 100M, 
                'E:\oradata\orcl\df2.dbf' size 200M,
                'E:\oradata\orcl\df3.dbf' size 300M;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
CREATE TABLESPACE maximo_data NOLOGGING
DATAFILE 'D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\maximo\maximo_data_0.ora' SIZE 16G,
         'D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata\maximo\maximo_data_1.ora' SIZE 16G
autoextend off
extent management local;
```